# IdeaVim: Make Cmd-A (macOS) select all text in visual mode

Tags: ideavim

I want Cmd-A (the macOS Command key, plus A) to select all text in visual mode, so I can e.g. indent or delete it using vim commands, Just like it does in MacVim. By default, it selects all text, but vim commands don't work on it.

I've put the following in `.ideavimrc`:

```
map <D-a> <esc>ggVG
```

And also removed the default Cmd-A shortcut in Preferences -> Keymap, because it seemed to override the vim one. But now Cmd-A just doesn't do anything.

I've found two workarounds so far, neither very satisfying. For both start out in normal-mode.

1. `ggVG`
2. press `v` followed by `Cmd-A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<D-*>` mappings are not supported in IdeaVim yet. Feel free to vote for [VIM-758](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-758) and contribute a fix to https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim.

**Edit:** You can check your effective mappings in IdeaVim via `:map`.

**Edit 2:** I've checked `<M-*>` mappings in IdeaVim 0.50 in macOS. They do exactly what you want, but with `<M-*>` instead of `<D-*>`. In my experiment, I've remapped `dd` to Command-A via:

```
map <M-a> dd
```

Important: the first time you open the IDE afterwards, there is a notification: "Using the shortcut from vim emulation. etc." Do **not** click the link in that notification, otherwise it will not use your shortcut defined in `.ideavimrc`.

Comment: thanks, so there is no workaround either? I can't use the keymap preferences to trigger some action?

Comment: @mb21 Could you try `<M-a>` for your mapping? To which key does it map to on macOS? Is it Command or something else?

Comment: Thanks! I clicked the unclear notification the first time (see my edit), that's why it didn't work.

Comment: This is no longer working for me in IdeaVim 2.1.0. Is anyone else experiencing this? 

Comment: <D-*> is working now as 2023-02-21